# MariaDB ColumnStore - docker - DBRM is readonly

Tags: docker, mariadb-columnstore

I make the following docker container

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  data:
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb/columnstore
    hostname: mcs1
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
```

I can connect to mariadb outside the container and can create a table with innodb engine.
But when I try to create a table with columnstore engine I got the following error:

`[HY000][1815] (conn=6) Internal error: Cannot execute the statement. DBRM is read only!`

the docker log show me

`InetStreamSocket::connect: connect() error: Connection refused to: InetStreamSocket: sd: 64 inet: 127.0.0.1 port: 8616`

Any idea to fix the issue?